# Entity SQL reference to the created model in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, entity-sql

I am trying to follow a textbook tutorial, I create the model but I don't know why I cannot reference to it.  Anyway, in collusion when I try to read the data from the database I get an exception, saying that the table was not found.  Thank you for any help and advice.

My Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
//using StockHistoryModel; This is my model and is not available.

static void Main(){
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["StockHistoryEntities"].ConnectionString;
  EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(connectionString);
  connection.Open();
  EntityCommand command = new EntityCommand("SELECT SymbolID FROM Shares",    
    connection);
  DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(
    CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
  while (reader.Read())
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetValue(0));
   }
}
```

Exception:

[image]

My Model:

[image]

Comment: Did you try executing query 'SELECT SymbolID FROM Shares' in SSMS? I mean in sql?

Comment: Show your connection string

Comment: This is the connection: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StockHistoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StockHistoryModel.csdl|res://*/StockHistoryModel.ssdl|res://*/StockHistoryModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=StockHistory;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: When you work with `EntityCommand`, you have to use ESQL instead of SQL. Try `"SELECT VALUE SymbolID FROM yourNamespace.Shares"` (tell me what is your namespace in your edmx)

Comment: I just tried but still I get the exception.  But why I cannot referent the namespace with using?

Comment: edmx namespace and c# namespace are different. You cannot use `using`. `using` is for c# namespace.

Comment: Ok, but why in my textboox shows to import with using?  Anyway, as long as I make it work I don't mind.

Comment: your `using` is used by c# compiler at compilation time. But your code is at runtime, you need to specify a namespace.Try: `"SELECT VALUE SymbolID FROM StockHistoryModel.Shares"` (assuming that `StockHistoryModel` is your namespace)

Comment: I realized I had a mistake. Please try: `"SELECT VALUE Shares.SymbolID FROM StockHistoryModel.Shares as Shares"` (assuming that `StockHistoryModel` is your namespace)

Comment: Still not working :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71406/discussion-between-doro-and-khanh-to).